# Modal not showing in when rendered in React component

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

**What I'm trying to do**: When I'm writing a project using React and Redux, I want to pop up a modal from `RecordTaskPopUp` component when the state `isTimeOut` of `ManageTimer` component is changed by a timer event (for readability purpose, I have directly defined `isTimeOut` to be `true` in the following code).

**Problem**: Modal not showing up on the page.

**What I have done to find the problem**:

1. I have changed `.modal {display: block}` in my css file but it still is not showing on the page.
2. I also try to render something else other than modal on my `RecordTskPopUp` component, it works perfectly fine. So I suppose the problem is with modal itself.
3. Paste the whole render snippet of `RecordTaskPopUp` from bootstrap document.

Can someone tell me what might be the possible cause of this problem? Thanks a lot!

```
class ManageTimer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isTimeOut: true
    }
  this.closePopUp = this.closePopUp.bind(this);
  }

  closePopUp() {
    this.setState({
    isTimeOut: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {this.state.isTimeOut ? 
      <RecordTaskPopUp
        closePopUp={this.closePopUp}/> : 
      <p>There is still time remaining</p> 
      }
    );
  }
}

const RecordTaskPopUp = ({closePopUp}) => {
   return (
      <div className="modal fade">
        <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title">Modal Header</h5>
              <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true" onClick={closePopUp}>&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>

            <div className="modal-body">
              <p> Modal Body</p>
            </div>

            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={closePopUp}>Close</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   );
};
```

Comment: The generic bootstrap modal uses javascript to be able to work properly. However, the way it is coded, is in the older style of dom rendering, which is completely different than how React does it. You are going to have to find a custom modal component built for react. I currently use "React Bootstrap". Your modal is never going to work if you are attempting to use the modal provided from the official Bootstrap source code.

Comment: But why when I use bootstrap classes like "btn" or "navbar", they work just fine. Is it that most complex components like "modal" all need a customized react component to use it?

Comment: Yeah that's the confusing part for beginners. I have been down that road too. The reason you can use those classes, are because they specifically relate to css classes. The css works just fine, but whenever you require some functionality that requires javascript, you have to leave the old bootstrap javascript way of doing stuff behind.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot! I learned there are several tools for using Bootstrap in React, eg: "react-bootstrap", 'reactstrap'. Do you have a specific reason for using "React Bootstrap"?

Comment: @DanielZuzevich do you want to paste your answer from the comment to the answer area so that I can accept your answer?

Comment: I just tend to go towards projects that I know have been around awhile and have a good follower base. So I know they aren't just going to dissappear and stop being maintained. Reactstrap looks pretty good though, and looks like it does v4. Its ultimately up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$('#mypopup').modal('toggle');
$('#mypopup').modal('show');
$('#mypopup').modal('hide');
```

in your `closePopUp()`

In your case:

```
  closePopUp (){
     $('#mypopup').modal('hide');   
  }
```

Dont forget to add `id="mypopup"` to your outer div:

```
<div className="modal fade" id="mypopup" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
```

Here is a JSFiddle based on your code https://jsfiddle.net/rafahoro/dsjoayrt/15/

Hope it helps.

Edited/added:
 The modal methods are documented in bootstrap pages http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods

Comment: Thanks! This solves my problem very well! May I know the reason for this to work?

Comment: I'm glad it solved your problem.
Edited the answer to link to documentation

Answer (score 1):

The generic bootstrap modal uses javascript to be able to work properly. However, the way it is coded, is in the older style of dom rendering, which is completely different than how React does it. You are going to have to find a custom modal component built for react. I currently use "React Bootstrap". Your modal is never going to work if you are attempting to use the modal provided from the official Bootstrap source code.